# Was wäre ein ehrlicheres Wort für den Euphemismus "Rettungsschirm"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, single-word-request

Im Duden finden sich nur Einträge zu [Rettungsschirm:](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rettungsschirm)

> (besonders Politik) Rettungspaket
>
> [Eu­ro-Ret­tungs­schirm](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Euro_Rettungsschirm), Eu­ro­ret­tungs­schirm, der
> Gesamtheit der Maßnahmen zur wirtschaftlichen Stabilisierung einzelner Länder der Eurozone

Kritiker dieses Begriffes führen an, diesen Propagandabegriff zu verwenden, sei nicht nur verschleiernd, sondern auch die Unterwerfung unter Herrschaftssprache (Falls nötig: [Begriffserklärung](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60WLlID124Y) [Herrschaftssprache](http://www.taz.de/!t5009720/)). Es ginge um "Gewinne privatisieren, Verluste hingegen sozialisieren", ohne dass dies im Wort selbst kenntlich wäre. Weder Ziel noch Vorgang korrekt zu benennen, ist suboptimal. Forderungen wie aus dem SZ-Magazin: "[Erspart uns den Euro-Neusprech](http://sz-magazin.sueddeutsche.de/texte/anzeigen/36290)" allein helfen da anscheinend nicht viel weiter als blanke Analysen wie [Neusprech: Rettungsschirm](http://www.zeitgeistlos.de/zgblog/2011/neusprech-rettungsschirm/).

Bei dem gedankenlosen Nachsprechen von "Rettungsschirm" handele es sich also um eine

> **[problemflankierende Sprachentwicklungsanästhesie](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/5867-problemflankierende_Sprachentwicklungsanaesthesie)**
> Bewußte sprachliche Verharmlosung, Verniedlichung, Schönrederei. Bestimmte Ziel-, Berufs-, Randgruppen oder Ereignisse werden sprachlich derart aufgehübscht, daß die wahre Dramatik, Misere, Bedeutung oder Herkunft bewußt verschleiert bzw. geschönt wird. Dieses Vokabular und diese Formulierungen (oft benutzt von Politikern) nennt man auch Herrschaftssprache, welche dem Gegenüber vermitteln soll: Diesen Satz habe ich nicht verstanden, kann ich nich' mitreden, bin ich zu blöd für!

Da der Duden es nicht fertigbringt den Begriff auch nur halbwegs sinnvoll zu erklären, zunächst eine sprachkritische Definition. Was scheinen die Nachrichtenverleser zu meinen, wenn sie von einem solchen sprechen:

> [**Rettungsschirm**](https://neusprech.org/rettungsschirm/)
> Wenn man etwas verkaufen will, gibt es zwei unfehlbare Möglichkeiten: man kann beim Käufer Wähler die Gier oder die Angst schüren. Erstere fällt irgendwie aus, wenn es darum geht, mitten in einer Krise 750 Milliarden Euro wegzuschenken, um <del>notleidende</del> [knauserige Banken](http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2010-05/kommentar-eu-rettungsschirm) zu beruhigen und Pleitiers über Wasser zu halten. Bleibt die Angst. Kein Wunder also, dass die Sprache im Zusammenhang mit der sogenannten Finanzkrise, (denn die Finanzen sind in gar keiner Krise, nur die Banken), vor Panikmetaphern nur so strotzt. Doch ob man sich damit wirklich einen Gefallen tut? Ein R. immerhin soll etwas bremsen, was sich ohne ihn im freien und garantiert tödlich endenden Fall befände. Gäbe es ihn nicht, bedeutet das, wäre der Euro erledigt. Doch so stimmt das nicht. Nochmal kurz zu den Ursachen: Geld war lange billig in Europa, weil Wirtschaft und Politik Angst vor einer Krise hatten und die Zinsen niedrig hielten. Daher haben sich einige Länder mehr davon geborgt, als für sie gut gewesen wäre. Sie haben über ihre Verhältnisse gelebt und sind nun bankrott – mit dem Ergebnis, dass die Krise letztlich noch viel schlimmer ist. [Das gleiche geschieht nun noch einmal](http://www.zeit.de/2010/19/Europa-Schuldenkrise), nur im größeren Maßstab. Wieder wird auf Pump finanziert, was sich eigentlich niemand leisten kann. Doch der Kapitalismus verzeiht solche Dummheit nicht, er ist ein [Nullsummenspiel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsummenspiel) – was einer gewinnt, muss jemand anderes verlieren. Der R. ist also gar keiner, denn er rettet nichts und niemanden. Das Ganze ist viel mehr, wenn man unbedingt einen griffigen Begriff sucht, eine Umwälzpumpe: Das Geld wird umgeschichtet von den vielen Steuerzahlern hin zu den wenigen, die an solchen Geschäften sehr [sehr viel verdienen](http://www.ftd.de/unternehmen/finanzdienstleister/:handelsgeschaeft-goldman-sachs-gewinnt-alle-tage/50112738.html).
> (Analyse von [Kai Biermann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_Biermann) [u.a. Autor der *Zeit*] veröffentlicht auf dem Blog, welches er mit dem Sprachwissenschaftler [Martin Haase](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Haase) veröffentlicht hat.)

Die gestellte Frage ist nun: mit welchem Alternativbegriff kann man die Sache weniger beschönigend ausdrücken, ohne dabei die Allgemeinverständlichkeit all zu sehr zu kompromittieren?

Gesucht wird ein einzelnes, besseres, treffenderes Wort. Existiert bereits eines?

Denn nochmal [laut der taz von oben](http://www.taz.de/!t5009720/):

> Nun gibt es allerdings immer Alternativen – wer das abstreitet, ist entweder dumm oder gemeingefährlich. Trifft beides zu, handelt es sich um die Regierung.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89778/discussion-on-question-by-langlangc-was-ware-ein-ehrlicheres-wort-fur-den-euphem).

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "Schuldenübernahme/Schuldentilgung"?

Answer (score 6):

Zunächst einmal sollte man die Fragestellung kritisch reflektieren. Der Begriff *Euro-Rettungsschirm* ist eine Metapher und transportiert implizit bestimmte Wertungen - ich würde sagen, sie transportiert die Assoziation einer *Notfallsituation*, in der der *abstürzende Euro* *aufgefangen* und damit *gerettet* wird. Sicherlich kann man auch unterstellen, dass diese Metapher bewusst gewählt wurde, um die entsprechenden Wertungen (Dringlichkeit, Alternativlosigkeit) zu implizieren. Diese strategische Wahl der implizit kommunizierten Konzepte ist typisch für die Sprache der Politik. Man hat diese Effekte, und auch ihren strategischen Einsatz unter dem Begriff *Framing* zusammengefasst, Arbeiten von George Lakoff, und im deutschen Sprachraum Elisabeth Wehling, sind hier in letzter Zeit wegweisend. Die Beobachtung, dass Sprache das Denken prägt, ist aber älter, schon Victor Klemperer hat die impliziten Konzeptualisierungen der Sprache des Dritten Reichs (in dem Klassiker *LTI. Notizbuch eines Philologen*, https://epdf.tips/lti-notizbuch-eines-philologen.html) kritisch analysiert.

Es ist aber auch so, dass jeder Begriff implizite Konnotationen und Wertungen transportiert, und dass es neutrale Begriffe schlechterdings nicht gibt, weil es keine metaphernfreie Sprache gibt, die ohne implizite Konzeptualisierungen auskäme (etwa George Lakoff und Mark Johnson: *Metaphors we live by*, eine Kopie findet man hier: http://shu.bg/tadmin/upload/storage/161.pdf)

Die Frage, welche Konzeptualisierung die "richtige", oder wie du schreibst "ehrliche" ist, das heißt, die wertneutrale, kann damit nicht beantwortet werden. Die Frage, welche Konzeptualisierung die *angemessene* ist, ist keine Frage für ein linguistisches Forum, sondern eine weltanschauliche Diskussion.

Dies vorausgeschickt, sehe ich folgende Möglichkeiten alternativer Benennungen, die ebenfalls metaphorischer Natur sind. Indem ich diese Worte nenne, distanziere ich mich ausdrücklich von den damit einhergehenden Wertungen. Ich möchte mich auf die politische Diskussion, welche Metaphorik hier die angemessene ist, nicht einlassen, ich denke, sie gehört nicht hierher, und ich persönlich bin dafür auch wirtschaftlich und politisch zu wenig informiert, um diese Diskussion führen zu können.

- *Austeritätsdiktat*
- *Stabilitätspakt*
- *Kreditschwemme*
- *Europäischer Länderfinanzausgleich* (in Analogie zum deutschen Länderfinanzausgleich)
- *EZB-Staatenfinanzierung* (betont, dass die EZB Staatsanleihen auf dem Sekundärmarkt kauft und damit alle Euro-Besitzer Staaten mitfinanzieren)
- *Europäische Insolvenzverschleppung*
- *Schuldenkrebs* (impliziert, dass die verschuldeten Staaten durch die Kredite nicht saniert werden könnten, und die EZB daher immer weiter Kredite geben werden muss.)
- *Co-Abhängigkeit der Eurozone* (siehe [Wikipedia: Co-Abhängigkeit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-Abh%C3%A4ngigkeit))
- *Finanzkolonialismus*
- *Europäische Bilanzenfälschung*

Sicher kommt man noch auf weitere Konzepte, wenn man sich mehr mit der Kritik an dem Euro-Rettungsschirm (mit der Kritik an der Sache, nicht mit der Kritik am Begriff) beschäftigt und versucht, die Kritik jeweils in eine Metapher zu übersetzen.

Answer (score 3):

Konkret im Zusammenhang mit dem Euro würde ich von einer **Kreditgarantie** oder **Sicherheitszusage** sprechen. Freilich unterstellt die Garantie, dass man auch tatsächlich in der Lage ist, eine solche zu leisten und das "Sicherheit" in Sicherheitszusage kann auch wieder als euphemistisch empfunden werden, aber "Sicherheiten" sind im Kreditwesen ein lange eingeführtes Wort und sollte seine emotionale Wirkung inzwischen weitgehend eingebüßt haben.

In anderen Zusammenhängen könnte ein Rettungsschirm eine andere, konkrete Bedeutung haben, aber meines Wissens ist im Zusammenhang mit dem Euro gemeint, dass verschiedene Länder für Banken bürgen. Also wäre auch **Bürgschaft** ein möglicher Ersatz.